# "changes.sty" package: How does one change default font size for margin comments?

Tags: changes

I am using the `changes` package.  The margin comments have larger font than the text in the main body.  I can't find any mention of font size settings [here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.withcode.pdf).

I can insert commands like `\tiny` at the start of the comment text, but unfortunately, the line spacing in the margin is *not* shrunk commensurately.  Also, for better signal-to-noise, it'd be better to set the default font size once rather than for each comment.

Comment: It seems the style of text in margin comments is controlled by `todonotes` package. Try `\usepackage[todonotes={textsize=tiny}]{changes}`. Check sec. 4.1.13 "todonotes" in `changes`' package manual. PS: Providing an [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is always recommended, and sometimes required.

Comment: Thank you, muzimuzhi.  Your solution worked.  Point noted about the MWE.  I thought it was a simple command that I was missing, such as with font sizing in general.  I would be glad to provide an MWE if prompted, e.g., if your optional `todonotes` argument hadn't worked, or even if it was pointed out as an MWE was needed because the problem wasn't trivial.  *Did you want to post your solution as the answer?*